# problem with juju on Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution

Tags: juju, cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

During the installation of Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution (step 4 [ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack](http://ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)) I've received an error with Juju. 
Juju made the bootstrapping of the node, the ubuntu installer started but at the end of the procedure the node went in shut down. I've tried to resolve that editing the environments.yaml file and added the bootstrap-timeout to 3600, (all vnode use the fastpath-installer),

**sudo nano /usr/share/openstack/templates/juju-env/maas.yaml**

like that

```
default: maas

environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://x.x.x.x/MAAS/'
    maas-oauth: 'LnLE8w3grRK6hLcVgF:xxxxxxx'
    admin-secret: richardsith
    default-series: trusty
    authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    apt-http-proxy: 'http://x.x.x.x:8000/'
    lxc-clone: true
    bootstrap-timeout: 3600

  openstack:
    type: openstack
    use-floating-ip: true
    use-default-secgroup: true
    network: ubuntu-net
    auth-url: http://keystoneurl:5000/v2.0/
    tenant-name: ubuntu
    region: RegionOne
    auth-mode: userpass
    username: ubuntu
    password: richardsith
```

and then I run the command

```
 $: sudo openstack-install
```

[image]

[image]

after that the node made the reboot and during the boot I saw that

[image]

after some minutes the installer went head

[image]

the node means ready but after few seconds went down, and on .commands.log the log is this

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9284133/

I've also try to make the bootstrapping manually with debug with juju receiving the following log http://paste.ubuntu.com/9342625/

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: Looks like a possible error within Juju, can you pastebin the juju logs?

Comment: the log is reported here http://paste.ubuntu.com/9327941/

Comment: Try bootstrapping on MAAS with juju directly, without the cloud installer. That has to work before the cloud installer can be tried.

Comment: I tried to install and update MaaS (1.7) and Juju via ppa stable (1.7) on a clear Virtual Ubuntu server. I've added some vnode on maas, made bootstrapping of juju environment install juju-gui on a node. Everything work very well. Tomorrow I'll try to make what you've suggested me on Canonical Distribution

Comment: I edited the post and added the log of that

Comment: I made a step forward..now juju deployed the vnode to user, finished almost all the steps. Now, the installer stopped its procedure during the deploy of landscape. I received the following error http://paste.ubuntu.com/9489697/, while the command juju status gives me that http://paste.ubuntu.com/9489797/. Now, to avoid to re-run from the begin there is a way to start just from this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This step has been resolved extended the bootstrap-timeout to 3600 in the last upgrade of Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution. 
To make that run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

See this link
https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/280#event-204277001

With this solution the installer, in my lab, has continued with the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked.

```
sunbeam cluster bootstrap
```