# Failed to bootstrap during Openstack autopilot installation

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I'm installing Openstack autopilot on Ubuntu 15.04 server. I've installed Maas and join nodes successfully. I tested Maas connection by installing juju and deploying service. but when I want to install openstack it encounters error in bootstraping.

I follow instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot

I debug installation and get these:

**config.yaml**

```
headless: true
install_type: OpenStack Autopilot
landscapecreds:
  admin_email: user@mail.com
  admin_name: admin
  maas_apikey: [redacted]
  maas_server: 10.1.0.100
  system_email: user@mail.com
maascreds:
  api_host: 10.1.0.100
  api_key: [redacted]
openstack_password: [redacted]
openstack_release: kilo
ubuntu_series: trusty
```

**command**

```
DEBUG_JUJU_BOOTSTRAP=1 sudo -E openstack-install -c config.yaml --debug
```

**commands.log**

```
[INFO: 12-30 01:18:40] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.24
[INFO: 12-30 01:18:40] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install', '-c', 'config.yaml', '--debug']
[INFO: 12-30 01:18:40] Running Kilo release
[INFO: 12-30 01:18:40] Performing a OpenStack Autopilot install
[INFO: 12-30 01:21:48] Bootstrapping Juju
[INFO: 12-30 01:21:49] Bootstrapping Juju
[ERROR: 12-30 01:22:11] Fatal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/installbase.py", line 150, in start
    self.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/installbase.py", line 134, in do_install
    self.loop, self.ui, self.config).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/landscape.py", line 80, in run
    self._do_install_existing_maas()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/landscape.py", line 42, in _do_install_existing_maas
    self.config, self.landscape_tasks).do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 131, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[INFO: 12-30 01:22:11] Stopping eventloop
[INFO: 12-30 01:22:11] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

when I tried to bootstrap manually. I got these error:

**command:**

```
 JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju/ juju bootstrap --debug
```

**Error:**

```
2015-12-29 22:10:53 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:129 Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
2015-12-29 22:10:53 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:22 destroying environment "maas"
2015-12-29 22:10:53 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:33 destroying instances
2015-12-29 22:10:54 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:53 destroying storage
2015-12-29 22:10:54 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: cannot start bootstrap instance: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR (('UNHANDLED', 'Unknown Error [sajjad-maas:pid=774:cmd=CreateHostMaps:ask=b3]'))
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Regards
Sajjad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem solved, respect to to this post [problem with juju on Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554329/problem-with-juju-on-ubuntu-openstack-canonical-distribution)

I've upgrade my region controller by these commands , after adding apt-repositories ([described here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot))

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I download latest images for 14.04 LTS from MAAS web UI, because my image was for two month ago.

And the installation of landscape auto-pilot done successfully. As a result It seems that if you want to install something, you must have the latest updates of everything.

Answer (score -1):

You can work around this by changing the image-stream value in your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` file from 'daily' to 'released'.